# python gzip file in memory and upload to s3

Tags: python, sed, gzip, boto, stringio

I am using python 2.7...

I am trying to cat two log files , get data from specific dates using sed. Need to compress the files and upload them to s3 without making any temp files on the system,

```
sed_command = "sed -n '/{}/,/{}/p'".format(last_date, last_date)
```

Flow :

1. cat two files .

Example : cat file1 file2

2. Run sed manipulation in memory.
3. compress the result in memory with zip or gzip.
4. Upload the compressed file in memory to s3.

I have successfully done this with creation of temp files on the system and removing them when the upload to s3 is completed. I could not find a working solution to get this working on the fly without creation of any temp files.

Comment: If you're on an EC2 instance, since you're in shell already, how about writing the output to a file in a tmpfs filesystem like `/run`. Then it would be about as in memory as doing it in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the gist of it:

```
conn = boto.s3.connection.S3Connection(aws_key, secret_key)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name, validate=True)
buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
writer = gzip.GzipFile(None, 'wb', 6, buffer)
writer.write(sys.stdin.read())
writer.close()
buffer.seek(0)
boto.s3.key.Key(bucket, key_path).set_contents_from_file(buffer)
buffer.close()
```

Comment: in python3 change cStringIO..StringIO() by io.StringIO

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a late answer, but I recently published a [package](https://github.com/omrikiei/aws_logging_handlers) that does just that, it's installable via pypi:

```
    pip install aws-logging-handlers
```

And you can find usage documentation on [git](https://github.com/omrikiei/aws_logging_handlers)